# How do we use the output of visualsearch.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm interested in using the [visualsearch.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/) control for my website but, having read through the documentation, I am still unclear regarding how to effectively obtain the output search collection data. Based on the example, the output string is constructed through serialization of the search collection. However, I was wondering if there is a way to access the search collection in a more array-like fashion (so that for/in loops can be used) rather than having to parse a single serialized string. Ultimately, I need to construct SQL queries from the search collection data.

If there is an even more efficient or appropriate way of accessing the search collection data, please let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: I succesfully use visualsearch.js in my app and I also had some troubles seting it up. However I'm not sure to understand what is your problem: you don't know how to use the facets output to filter your collection?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: The only output I am familiar with is the searchCollection.serialize() method, but it is not very useful for my purposes. Being able to access the data in a more array-like fashion would be more suitable. I'm brand-new to javascript so I might be missing some fundamentals... Could you elaborate more on "facets output to filter your collection"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as far as i know there are 2 ways to fetch data from visual search
it is also directly explained in their documentation in [usage #4](http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/#usage)

1. like you said, the stringified version of the search.

   ```
   visualSearch.searchBox.value();

   // returns: 'country: "United States" state: "New York" account: 5-samuel title: "Pentagon Papers"'
   ```
2. or the facetted object to loop over

   ```
   visualSearch.searchQuery.facets();

   // returns: [{"country":"United States"},{"state":"New York"},{"account":"5-samuel"},{"title":"Pentagon Papers"}]
   ```

   as you can see, this option gives you an array, per facet that was filtered on, and for each asset the value that was entered.

Answer (score 3):

mhmmm.. ok, the answer is not so straightforward. I would suggest you to get some practice with backbone structure just making some modification to the todo-list app. It is a great startpoint. So you get familiar with some of the wonderful [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) methods for collections

The Basic idea is the following:
With visualsearch you can obtain a list of "facets", that is to say an array of key/values objects.

```
 var myFacets = visualSearch.searchQuery.facets();
 //my facets is then something like [{"field1":"value1-a"},{"field2":"value2-c"}]
```

after this you can use `myFacets` elements to iterativrely filter you collection with the WONDERFUL [`filter`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter) method hinerithed from [_underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#) lib.

How to do it? You can use the _.each method in the underscore lib

```
    _.each(myFacets,function(facet){
                myCollection=myCollection.filter(function(item){
                    return item.get(facet.get('category')) == facet.get('value');
                    });
                });
            }
```

Here you use the filter method of backbone.js, which returns only the values are true according to your clause. So, you filter your collection once for each single facet. It is like telling to javascript: "Return me only the elements of the collection which match with this facets (value)", and you do it iteratively for all the different facets you got.

Hope this helps.

Ah.. one last thing, just to mess ideas up :-)  :Visualsearch is built on backbone.js, and the searchQuery object is nothing but a backbone Collection, so you can use the methods and the properties of the basic backbone collection. Read this line again if this is not clear, because this can be a  key point for future implementations! :-)

I suggest you to have a look at the search_jquery.js file in the lib/js/models folder. It's very interesting...